# Python code to calculate the maximal amount of baggage is allowed using recursive function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, recursion, count

I am new to python and I have an assignment, I need to write a recursive function that takes two arguments (Weights, W), weights is the list of weights of baggage and W is the maximal weight a student can take, in python 2.7 that calculates the maximal amount of baggage a student can take and does not pass the maximal limit (W), for example if:

```
>>> calc_max_baggage([5], 0)
>>> 0
>>> calc_max_baggage ([1, 1, 1], 5)
>>> 3
>>> calc_max_baggage([4, 2, 3, 1], 5)
>>> 2
```

This is my code but it returns error:

```
def calc_max_baggage (weights, W):
weights = []
res = []
W = int
def number_of_index(weights, W, i): 
    if max(weights) > W:
        return res
    else:
        count += i in weights

return calc_max_baggage()
```

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       calc_max_baggage ([5], 0)
>     File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/לימודים/פייתון Python/עבודות בית/ex6/test_ex6.py", line 12, in calc_max_baggage
>       return calc_max_baggage()
>   TypeError: calc_max_baggage() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)

I am totally not sure about my code I think its totally wrong

Weights is the list of weights and W is the maximal weight.
**Given this, I want to know how many items from the weights[] list can be brought on the plane.**
***I can't change the funtion `calc_max_baggage(weights, W)` that takes two arguments.**

W can also be negative, in that case the function returns 0.

**IT MUST BE SOLVED WITH RECURSION ONLY AND WITHOUT LOOPS**

Thanks

Comment: What have **you** tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: I edited the post above

Comment: You need to call the function with the two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

We can slightly modify the `powerset` recipe from the [itertools doumentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#recipes) to not use an explicit loop:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(map(lambda r: combinations(s, r), range(len(s)+1)))
```

For each combination of luggage, we can filter out all of those that exceed the maximum weight, then take the one with the most items:

```
def calc_max_baggage(weights, W):
    weights = powerset(weights)
    filtered = filter(lambda items: sum(items) <= W, weights)
    filtered = chain(filtered, ((),)) 
    return max(filtered, key=len)
```

`filtered = chain(filtered, ((),))` is so if `W` is negative we return no bags anyways, even though technically the sum of their weights is greater than `W`.

This will return the actual set of items, rather than its length, but you can easily convert it.

```
>>> calc_max_baggage([4, 2, 3, 1], 5)
(4, 1)
>>> calc_max_baggage ([1, 1, 1], 5)
(1, 1, 1)
>>> calc_max_baggage([5], 0)
()
```

If you need a recursive component, you can define `powerset` recursively, though it's markedly less efficient

```
def powerset(seq):
    if not seq:
        return ((),)
    else:
        head, *tail = seq
        tail_pow = powerset(tail)
        with_head = tuple(map(lambda t: (head,) + t, tail_pow))
        return with_head + tail_pow
```

Comment: Well your answer is correct but I must use recursion to solve the question and without using any loops.

Comment: This code doesn't use any (explicit) loops.  There's probably a recursive way of defining `powerset`, but I'm not sure off the top of my head how we would do it.

Comment: @Thaa'erSawaid See my edit.  You may want to read your assignment closely before submitting this.  I'm making liberal use of `map` to get around the "no loops" requirement.