# python printing all subsets of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

[1,2,3]
I have this list and want to print all subsets of this list using recursion.  I am getting the output using the following code but is there any better/easier way? Without typecasting it to a set.

```
def recur_subset(arr):
    if len(arr)==0:
        print(arr)
    else:
        for i in range(0, len(arr)):
            print(arr[0:i+1])
        for j in range(2, len(arr)):
            print([arr[0], arr[j]])

        return recur_subset(arr[1:len(arr)])
```

Comment: I recently wrote a [recursive `powerset` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53782303/6779307) as part of another answer.  Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools` to do the heavy lifting:

```
import itertools

def recur_subset( s, l=None ):
    if l == None:
        l = len(s)
    if l > 0:
        for x in itertools.combinations( s, l ):
            print(list(x))
        recur_subset( s, l-1 )
```

Note: This only prints non-empty subsets; add `else: print([])` at the end to include the empty subset.

Comment: i am new to python don't know much about different packages just numpy

Comment: That's why I posted this!